# Xcode Apple mach-o linker (id) error after creating AdHoc scheme

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting Apple mach-o linker error after creating AdHoc scheme. All I did was make a duplicate of release scheme (I did not have Adhoc in Code signing Identity), assigned build configuration as AdHoc by editing scheme and chose AdHoc provisioning profile from the Build Settings. Everything works fine in release and debug builds. What's wrong?

Error:

> Ld
>   /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ahialnkqxudemgdnsueegfkiqmpd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp
>   normal arm64
>       cd /Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ahialnkqxudemgdnsueegfkiqmpd/Build/Products/AdHoc-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries
>   -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/ParseCrashReporting -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/GoogleConversionTrackingSDK-iOS-3.2.0
>   -L/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/GoogleConversionTrackingSDK-iOS-3.4.0
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ahialnkqxudemgdnsueegfkiqmpd/Build/Products/AdHoc-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/Google/Frameworks -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleAppUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/HockeySDKCrashOnly -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDK.embeddedframework
>   -F/Users/Jenaveve/NachiketApps/iOS/MyApp_ios/HockeySDK-iOS/HockeySDKCrashOnly
>   -filelist /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ahialnkqxudemgdnsueegfkiqmpd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ahialnkqxudemgdnsueegfkiqmpd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp_lto.o
>   -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -ObjC -lBolts -lGoogleAnalytics -lMZAppearance -lMZFormSheetPresentationController -lParse -lParseCrashReporting -lParseCrashReportingLib -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lstdc++.6 -lz -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreText -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework Foundation -framework GGLCore -framework GGLSignIn -framework GoogleAppUtilities -framework GoogleAuthUtilities -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework
>   GoogleNetworkingUtilities -framework GoogleSignIn -framework
>   GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MessageUI
>   -framework QuartzCore -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -framework MessageUI -framework CoreFoundation -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework UIKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework SafariServices -framework AddressBook -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Accelerate -framework
>   AdSupport -lsqlite3 -framework QuartzCore -framework AudioToolbox
>   -framework GoogleMaps -lstdc++.6 -lz -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation
>   -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -lsqlite3.0 -lc++ -framework FBSDKCoreKit -licucore -framework MapKit -lGoogleConversionTracking -framework GLKit -framework OpenGLES -framework ImageIO -framework CoreData -framework AVFoundation -lPods-MyApp -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ahialnkqxudemgdnsueegfkiqmpd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/Jenaveve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-ahialnkqxudemgdnsueegfkiqmpd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/AdHoc-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp

Comment: Could please add the full error description. You can edit you app name and sensitive information but the error description could help a lot. Mostly the error lies in the first few sentences.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: From what I have read there isn't any particular reason for the error. However, the derived data may be causing problems. Try deleting the derived data of the project and rebuilding it. If you don't know how I will write you a step by step guide.

Comment: I don't know how to do it..please tell

Answer (score 0):

In order to clean the derived data you have to do the following steps:

- Open Xcode
- open your project
- Clicke the "Xcode" in your top left corner while you are in your project
- On the drop down select the "Preferences..."
- A new window appeares. You will go to the far right to the tab "Locations" and click it.
- Now you will see a label named: "Derived Data:" "Default". Under it is a grey text which starts with "/Users..." and an arrow sign. Click the little grey arrow.
- You will now be presented with a Finder window named "Xcode". Inside of it is a Folder named "DerivedData". Double click and open it.
- Delete everything inside it.
- Rebuild your project (Clean and Build).

Your error should disappear. You can repeat these steps from time to time since Xcode doesn't automatically delete that junk.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting my scheme and making a new one for AdHoc. Don't know the reason behind this..